# Does $x^*\in \arg\max_x \mathbb E(f(\theta,x))$ imply $\mathbb E\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(\theta,x^*)\right)=0$?

Tags: probability, optimization, expected-value

If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, and $x^*\in \arg\max_x f(x)$, then $f'(x^*)=0$. Moreover, if $f$ is concave, or quasiconcave,  then this condition is also sufficient, i.e. $x^*\in \arg\max_x f(x)$ iff $f(x^*)=0$.

**Is there an analogous condition for random functions $f$?**

That is, assume differentiable $f:\Theta\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. Is it true under some conditions that

$$x^*\in \arg\max_x \mathbb E(f(\theta,x)) \quad\text{implies}\quad \mathbb E\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(\theta,x^*)\right)=0,$$

for a random variable $\theta$? And does "implies" similarly become "iff" when we assume $f$ is concave in $x$ (or in both $\theta$ and $x$)? Do we need to assume something about the distribution of $\theta$?

Comment: Note that if $f$ is concave in $x$ then, $g(x)\overset{\Delta}=E[f(\theta,x)]$ is concave. Further, if $f$ is continuousy differentiable, you have Leibniz rule. The assumption on the distribution of $\theta$ is so that $E(\left|f(\theta,x)\right|)<\infty$.

Comment: I think you are looking for conditions that guarantee exchange of gradient and expectation operators. Theorem 7.44 in [this book](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Alex_Shapiro/SPbook.pdf) may be useful to you.